Is there a closed form solution for an arc through a point Q and tangential to 2 circles?
A small extension is to be programmed for a CAD system. So far, the system can create a circular arc with a specified radius tangential to two circles. The radii r1 and r2 of the circles and the distance D between their centers are given. You can find a variety of solutions on the web.
Now the circular arc that is tangential to the circles should run through a point Q (current mouse pointer). The radius r of the circular arc and the contact points P1 and P2 should be calculated.

So far I haven't found a closed form solution for this, but was only able to solve the problem by iterating r - not the best solution in terms of the CAD system, as it is sometimes very slow and not so precise. Can someone help?

If left circle center is (0,0) for simplicity, then we can write system of three quadratic equations for three unknowns mx, my, R
(mx-qx)^2+(my-qy)^2=R^2 
mx^2+my^2=(R-r1)^2
(D-mx)^2+my^2=(R-r2)^2 

You can try to solve this system by hands or with some math packet like Maple, Mathematica/(https://www.wolframalpha.com), by I think that formulas will be very long.
And such system have 6 (I think) solutions (some might be imaginary) - wanted one, small circle between your circles with outer tangency, large circles with one outer tangency and one inner tangency and so on, so you have to separate wanted solution (sign of my differs from qy and so on)
P.S. How wolframalpha solves

Thanks a lot!
Funny, but I had set already M1 to (0|0) and set up the second and third of your equations before I ran into trouble and asked for help. A third equation with sine and arctan was not successful. When changing the above drawing by moving Q to the left, I could comprehend your first equation and could see the rectangular triangle and the Pythagoras equation. As you said, the solutions are very long but they work well in Excel. Now, I will deal with the special scenarios, e.g. r1=r2, Q lies on the circle or on the tangent,...
